# Not able to update mongo collection using Bulkwrite

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having the mongo collection with the following fields

Sno1
Sno2
Location

The data in the collection is in the format

```
Sno1    Sno2   Location
--------------------------------
1000    2000   Hyderabad
```

I want to update the location as 'Chennai'. When I use the bulkWrite method on MongoCollection class, it returns the following exception

```
Here is the snippet

mongoColl.bulkWrite(docs, writeOptions);  --> docs is List<InsertOneModel<Document>> 


BulkWriteError(index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection'
```

There is a index created on Sno1 & Sno2 fields. How can I update the collection? I don't want to drop the index. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you need to update all documents with the same update (e.g. change location for all docs to a constant value) or every document should have different updates?

Comment: @geobreze I have to update all the documents with different locations based on Sno1 & Sno2

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOneModel`, so mongo will try updating one (or many) fields of **existing** documents.

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");

List<UpdateOneModel<Document>> updateList = List.of(
                new UpdateOneModel<>(new Document(Map.of("col1", "val1")), Updates.set("field", "1")),
                new UpdateOneModel<>(new Document(Map.of("col1", "val2")), Updates.set("field", "2")));
BulkWriteOptions options = new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false);
collection.bulkWrite(updateList, options);
```

If you need an upsert behaviour, you can use `com.mongodb.client.model.ReplaceOneModel` with `ReplaceOptions.upsert(true)`:

```
ReplaceOptions replaceOptions = new ReplaceOptions().upsert(true);
List<ReplaceOneModel<Document>> replaceList = List.of(
                new ReplaceOneModel<>(new Document(Map.of("col1", "val3")), new Document(Map.of("col1", "val3", "field", "1")), replaceOptions),
                new ReplaceOneModel<>(new Document(Map.of("col1", "val4")), new Document(Map.of("col1", "val4", "field", "2")), replaceOptions));
collection.bulkWrite(replaceList, options);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it. Can we update bulk instead of One?

Comment: We're creating a list of `UpdateOneModel` and then mongo driver will execute them as a bulk operation. UpdateMulti is used when you need to apply _same_ update to many documents.

Comment: We are having InsertOneModel class as part of mapping. When I try to replace with ReplaceOneModel, it gives compilation error of unchecked assignment as it doesnt have Document as one of the parameter

Comment: What version of mongo driver are you using?

Comment: Oh, I got it. In the `ReplaceOneModel`'s constructor first document is a query which is finding element for replacement. You need to specify it if you want to update documents because mongo driver can't figure it out by itself

Comment: How can I change it? Any idea

Comment: To update element (or many elements) in mongo you _always_ need to provide a query pointing to which documents you're updating